# Fetch video in AVPlayer from API in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift3, avplayer

I am able to run the local video in AVPlayer. But I couldn't fetch the video from JSON in swift 3. I searched for it but couldn't find the appropriate solution in Swift 3. How to fetch video from JSON in Swift 3? I am beginner in Swift.

I have JSON as:

```
 {
 "status": "Success",
 "course_summary": "<p>Laravel is one of the most popular PHP frameworks </p>",
 "course_video": "course.mkv"
}
```

Code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import Alamofire

class CourseSchedule: UIViewController {

var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
var player:AVPlayer?
var dictDataContent:NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
var strd : NSString?
var dictData:NSArray = NSArray()
var appDictionary: String?

@IBOutlet weak var courseSummary: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var videoPreviewLayer: UIView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let def = self.dictDataContent.value(forKey: "course_summary") as! String!
    let htmlData = NSString(string: def!).data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue)
    let attributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: htmlData!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)

    courseSummary.attributedText = attributedString
    courseSummary.textColor = UIColor.white
    courseSummary.font = UIFont(name: "Palatino", size: 14)


    //For local video to play in AVPlayer.

    let videoString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Working-Space", ofType: ".mp4")
    if let path = videoString {
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url as URL)
        self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
        self.playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        self.playerController.player = self.player
        playerController.view.frame = videoPreviewLayer.frame
        self.addChildViewController(playerController)
        self.videoPreviewLayer.addSubview(playerController.view)
        playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
        self.playerController.player?.play()
    }
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            self.player?.play()
        }
    })
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
}  
}




//HOMEVC

import UIKit
import Alamofire


class HomeVC: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var test: UIView!
var strid : NSString?
var strd : NSString?
var dictData:NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
var strd2 : NSString?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    self.setupPages()
  }


func setupPages() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var controllerArray: [UIViewController] = []
    let strinDuration:NSString = NSString(format:"http://rillmark.academy/api/rillmark-academy/course/course-content-detail?id=%@",strid!) as String as String as NSString
    print("strid",strid!)
    let collectionviewone: String = strinDuration as String
    Alamofire.request(collectionviewone, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response.result)
            if let JSON = response.result.value{
               self.dictData = (JSON as AnyObject) as! NSDictionary
                print("self.dictData",self.dictData)
                let firstVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CourseContentTable") as! CourseContentTable
                firstVC.title = "Course Content"
                firstVC.dictDataContent = self.dictData
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JSON you won't actually be sending the video. JSON is essentially Key:Value data. You could have the JSON send the video data or a link to download the video from. However currently by the looks of it you have:

```
{"course_video":"course.mkv"}
```

In other words you have types:

```
{String:String}
```

I would recommend passing a link through the json and then downloading the corresponding video. Have a look at [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) it's great for HTTP requests and handling your download. Once you have the video data you can use AVPlayer to play it.

Comment: Now, I have included the next view controller's content too. Here, I have fetched API using Alamofire. The JSON I have written above about video is dummy one. That's for privacy concern. Now, my question is how to play that video using AVPlayer in Swift 3?